# How many ways are there to distribute hands of 5 cards to each of four players from the standard deck of 52 cards?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games

The answer is $\frac{52!}{(5!\times 5!\times 5!\times 5!\times 32!)}
= 1.4782628e+24$

This reminds me of that if I have to select 7 objects from 3 types with infinite supply:

oo|oo|ooo

I know that it's no necessary to use the bar in this question because each person has the same numbers of the cards, but I still want to try to add 4 bars.

That is:

5 cards for person1 | 5 cards for person2 | 5 cards for person3 | 5 cards for person4 | undealt cars

so the equation is: $\frac{56!}{(5!\times 5!\times 5!\times 5!\times 32!\times 4!)}=5.4295116e+29$

What's wrong with my idea?

Comment: You keep saying 7 cards but the title and calculations are for 5.  You are trying to use stars and bars but it is not clear what you are doing.  It is better just to select five cards for the first person in $_{52}C_5$ ways, then five for the second in $_{47}C_5$ ways, and so on.  That is where the accepted solution comes from.

Comment: okay, I edited it...

Comment: Regarding the correct answer, see [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), and in particular, scroll down to see similar application.

Answer (score 1):

Stars and bars is useful for cases where the number of cards each person gets is not fixed and the cards are considered identical.  You don't care about which cards each person gets, just how many.  You then place the bars to show how many cards each person gets.  For example, if you were distributing $52$ cards to five people with no restriction that any person get any cards, you would imagine adding one to each hand and distributing $57$ cards to five people with each one getting at least one.  You would imagine $57$ stars and place four bars to separate the cards that each one gets.  There are $56$ places for bars, so there are $_{56}C_4$ ways to do this.  In this case all the cards get distributed to somebody.  This is very different from the problem you are working.

Comment: @amWhy:  OP specifically asked why the idea was wrong.  I would have been more explicit on what was wrong if I could understand the idea better.

Comment: Yes I see that more clearly now.  But it seems like the OP doesn't understand why the multinomial was used in the (correct) solution.  But I understand, you are not obliged to answer both "Why not this solution?" as well "Why that solution?".